# How to return default PS1 prompt?

Tags: bash, themes

After installing docker (I definitely think this is about docker) I got changed `cmd-label`. For instance, it was like `username@root8hgf858$: your_command` to `[:/home/username] $`.

How can I fix it? I've checked current theme in the system settings - it's ok.

screenshot:

[image]

```
[:/home/imran] $ grep PS1 .bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/bash.bashrc:[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
/etc/bash.bashrc:PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
/etc/skel/.bashrc:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
/etc/skel/.bashrc:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
/etc/skel/.bashrc:    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Comment: Look for `PS1` in your `.bashrc`, etc.

Comment: @muru i can't find something like PS1 in my .bashsrc

Comment: You are still using bash, right? What does `grep PS1 ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/skel/.bashrc` say?

Comment: @muru here's output: http://pastebin.com/hjLUnjTt

Comment: Looks like something or the other modified your `.bashrc`, since there's no mention of `PS1` in it at all. The question is, where is PS1 being set then? O.o For the moment, make a backup of your `.bashrc` and restore the original: `cp ~/.bashrc{,.bak}; cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` and start a new shell.

Comment: @muru Yeah! It works ;) I think, you should post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: If nothing of value was lost, sure.

Comment: @muru hm, i don't remember exactly, but should this looks like "user@user-bla-bla-bla" instead of "user@root"?

Comment: It should look like `user@hostname`, where hostname is typically `name-desktop` or `name-laptop` for Ubuntu desktop installations.

Comment: @muru if so, it's ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like something or the other modified your `.bashrc`, since there's no mention of `PS1` in it at all. For the moment, make a backup of your `.bashrc` and restore the original, and start a new shell:

```
cp ~/.bashrc{,.bak}
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

`/etc/skel` contains a skeleton profile used for setting up a new user's home directory, so it should contain the original `.bashrc` you had.

The question is, where is PS1 being set then? Perhaps the new `.bashrc` is sourcing other files, so you should examine `.bashrc.bak` to see what changes happened.

Answer (score 7):

The prompt is set by using the `PS1` variable. This can be defined in several places depending on your setup. If the new prompt is specific to your user, you can run the following command to check which file it is defined in:

```
grep -H PS1 ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login
```

If that returns nothing, broaden the search (some of these files shouldn't be relevant but these are all the files that can be read by default bash so you may as well include even unlikely culprits such as `~/.bash_aliases`):

```
grep -H PS1 ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases \
    /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
```

Once you have identified the file, open it in a text editor and set your `PS1` to whatever you like.