# PS1 Prompt Only Showing "$" For Domain Users

Tags: command-line, networking, server, prompt

Regardless of which directory I'm in the PS1 prompt only displays `$` for domain users, whereas, if I login using a local user the prompt displays as expected.

The `~/.bashrc` file for the test domain user has been restored as per the instructions [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574485/how-to-return-default-ps1-prompt)

If I `su` into a local user and then back into the domain user the prompt displays correctly.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

The contents of this user's `.bashrc` are:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

And the contents of the `.profile` file are:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: What do you mean by domain-user ? Logging in via ssh ?

Comment: What happens if you start an interactive bash shell after login as domain user (i.e. just type `bash`)? My guess would be that the domain user's login shell is not checking for and sourcing the `~/.bashrc` file (compare how the default `~/.profile` does it).

Comment: @serg I mean a user that has logged in using their credentials from the AD domain

Comment: @steeldriver that does the trick, how can I get it to do that automatically? Apologies if that's a basic question, I'm new to managing a domain linked server.

Comment: What is the domain users' login shell? did you copy the default `.profile` from /etc/skel or just the `.bashrc`?

Comment: Just the `.bashrc`. It didn't appear to have created a `.profile` file so I've now copied the `.profile` which seems to have not made a difference. As for the login shell, I have no idea if I'm honest, I just connect over SSH and assumed it would be the same as the default, but apparently not.

Comment: Basically, what steeldriver said. Look into your `~/.profile`. On typical Ubuntu system, the `~/.profile` checks if you're running `bash` and  sources `~/.bashrc`. Likely is that yours is missing that part.

Comment: Check your login shell via `ls -l  /proc/$$/exe`

Comment: @steeldriver  please write an answer once you guys figure this out. I have to run

Comment: @Serg, it appears to be `/bin/dash`. If it's of any relevance, the `passwd` file entry for `sssd` is: `sssd:x:130:137:SSSD system user,,,:/var/lib/sss:/bin/false`

Comment: @JamesHughes I'm not familiar with `sss` but I doubt the shell / password entry of the `sssd` user itself is relevant here: there's likely an `sssd.conf` file somewhere that specifies the default shell

Comment: Yep, what you see is the proper prompt for `dash`.  Since you said you're logging in via   `ssh`, look at ssh man page,it has certain config files what can run before logging in, so you should be able to source .bashrc from there, but what you really want to do is change interactive shell to bash. dash is very minimalistic and isn't really for interaactive use, unless you know how to use vim editing mode

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) the contents of your `~/.bashrc`; ii) the contents of your `~/.profile` and iii) tell us whether you have a `~/.bash_profile` file and, if you do, show us the contents of that as well. This comes down to the [different types of shell session](http://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695) and will be easy to solve if you show us these files.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks, it'll have to wait til monday, I'm home for the weekend now. I'll get back to you all.

Comment: added information as promised @terdon

Comment: Thanks, but you missed one. Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` file? And what files are these? A normal user's or a "domain" user's?

Comment: They're a "domain" user's but it would appear I've fixed the problem anyway. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be that when creating a new account for the domain user the `sssd` service was setting the dafault shell to be `dash`.

The solution to this is to edit the `sssd.conf` file to include the following:

```
[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash

[pam]
default_shell = /bin/bash
```

Which ensures that all domain users are created with their default shells set to bash.